# How to display unique entries from a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got this table

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ ID ║  Name        ║ Age  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ John         ║   36 ║
║  2 ║ Andre        ║   48 ║
║  3 ║ John         ║   21 ║
║  4 ║ Joel         ║   59 ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

How can I display only those names from table that are unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler method is to use the [DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_distinct.asp) keyword

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM t;
```